# IOHID: add trackpad to matching dictionary

Tags: c, hid, iokit

I'm trying to add the property of trackpads to a dictionary passed to a `IOHIDManager`. This manager will look at all pointer control devices. This works for mouse as so:

```
CFArrayRef matches;
{
    CFMutableDictionaryRef mouse = myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary(0x01, kHIDUsage_GD_Mouse); //works
    CFMutableDictionaryRef pointer   = myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary(0x01, kHIDUsage_GD_Pointer); //does not track
    CFMutableDictionaryRef matchesList[] = {pointer, mouse};
    matches = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)matchesList, 2, NULL);
}

IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatchingMultiple(hidManager, matches);
```

I cannot get it to pick up on trackpad events. The only trackpad I have to test with is the Apple trackpad and this does not seem to be working.
The page listing all the constants is [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-315.7.16/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDUsageTables.h). What do I need to add in my matching dictionary to get this?

EDIT:
`myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary()` is implemented as so:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary(UInt32 usagePage,  UInt32 usage){

    CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0
                                                            , & kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
                                                            , & kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    if (!dict)
        return NULL;

    CFNumberRef pageNumberRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, & usagePage);
    if (!pageNumberRef) {
        CFRelease(dict);
        return NULL;
    }
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey), pageNumberRef);
    CFRelease(pageNumberRef);

    CFNumberRef usageNumberRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, & usage);
    if (!usageNumberRef) {
        CFRelease(dict);
        return NULL;
    }
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, CFSTR(kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey), usageNumberRef);
    CFRelease(usageNumberRef);
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The touchpad on my rMBP has a bunch of "usage" declarations in its report descriptor, one of them is

```
0x05, 0x0D,        // Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x09, 0x05,        // Usage (Touch Pad)
```

I suspect this corresponds to

```
myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary(kHIDPage_Digitizer, kHIDUsage_Dig_TouchPad);
```

Depending on what exactly your code for `myCreateDeviceMatchingDictionary` is.

You can read the report descriptor for all your HID devices using a command like this:

```
ioreg -irc IOHIDDevice -w 0
```

And picking out the "ReportDescriptor" properties.

**Note: LONG output, best redirect it to a file.**

Comment: Thanks, I've added the pair you mentioned, but no luck. here is what the command produces (which is what you mentioned) `"DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=1,"DeviceUsage"=2},{"DeviceUsagePage"=1,"DeviceUsage"=1},{"DeviceUsagePage"=13,"DeviceUsage"=5})` , im suspecting all these have to be in one matching dict together as opposed to separate ones like my code

Comment: although these seem to be the correct codes, trackpads events are still not picked up with this :/

Comment: I'll try to find time to give this a try sometime soon. I assume there's a reason you can't do what you're trying to do at the CGEvent level?

Comment: Correct, I'm looking at identifying events by their device - getting the product id. Thanks for that, appreciate it.

Comment: @OrangePot were you able to get events ?

Comment: So `kHIDUsage_GD_Mouse` works on the trackpad for newer macbooks (probably ~2016 onwards) but still older trackpads (mine is 2013 retina) I cannot get to work. I have tried combinations of digitizer / touchpad. Any luck anybody?